# ¿Cómo hacer un update en Linq?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

Investigando al respecto la sintaxis de hacer un *update* en Linq, me he encontrado con distintos resultados, he visto que algunos lo hacen con un `foreach`, otros sin este y he quedado bastante confundido.

¿Cuál es el modo mas tradicional o estándar para hacer un *update* simple en Linq?

Anexo parte de mi consulta Linq, que tenía pensado usar para el *update*.

```
public EntrevistaIdiomaModel Visto(int id)
{
    EntrevistaIdiomaModel model = new EntrevistaIdiomaModel();

    var query = from a in db.EntrevistaIdioma
                where a.EntrevistaIdiomaID == id
                select new EntrevistaIdiomaModel
                {

                };

    model = query.SingleOrDefault();

    return model;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *¿Cuál es el modo mas tradicional o estándar para hacer un update simple en Linq?*

No existe modo tradicional, pero sí un estándar, todo depende de lo que desees hacer, lo cual nos limita a hacer una actualización de datos a un *`único registro`* o *`múltiples registros`*:

1. Hacer un *update* a un único registro. Básicamente es obtener el registro, modificar las propiedades necesarias y posteriormente guardar los cambios:

   ```
   var query = (from a in db.EntrevistaIdioma
               where a.EntrevistaIdiomaID == id
               select a).FirstOrDefault();

   query.PropiedadA = "Valor A";
   query.PropiedadB = "Valor B";
   query.PropiedadC = "Valor C";

   db.SubmitChanges();
   ```
2. Hacer un *update* a múltiples registros. El principio es el mismo, obtener el registro, recorrer los resultados obtenidos para modificar cada registro y al final, guardar los cambios:

   ```
   var query = (from a in db.EntrevistaIdioma
               select a).ToList();

   foreach(var item in query) {
       item.PropiedadA = "Valor A";
       item.PropiedadB = "Valor B";
       item.PropiedadC = "Valor C";
   }

   db.SubmitChanges();
   ```

En resumen, la única diferencia entre usar o no un `foreach` depende de si es un registro el que deseeas modificar o una serie de registros.

Answer (score 3):

Primero debes hacerlo de esta forma:

1. Consultar a la base de datos la fila que vas a afectar:

   ```
   var query = from ord in db.Orders
               where ord.OrderID == 11000
               select ord;
   ```
2. Ejecuta la consulta y cambia los valores de columna que deseas cambiar:

   ```
   foreach (Order ord in query)
   {
       ord.ShipName = "Mariner";
       ord.ShipVia = 2;
   }
   ```
3. Enviar los datos:

   ```
   try
   {
       db.SubmitChanges();
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(e);
   }
   ```

Comment: Bueno, si vas a afectar una sola fila, no hay necesidad de hacer un `foreach` :)

Comment: Bueno, puede ser que tenga mas casos, ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Yo realizo los *updates* de esta forma:

```
DatabaseEntities entities = new DatabaseEntities (); //entidad de base de datos

var oportunidad = entities.lead.Where(l => l.id == oportunidad_id).FirstOrDefault(); //consultas por ID en la tabla 'lead'

oportunidad.lead_state_id = 13;  //actualizas las propiedades de 'oportunidad'
oportunidad.observacion = observacion;
entities.SaveChanges();  //guardas cambios
```